# There has been an error processing your request. Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number:

Tags: error, exception

I get an error page in Magento that states:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: [some long number]

What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Is that an Apache error?  Find it's error log and look at the last few errors.  If you still can't work it out copy them to the end of your question.

Comment: @clockworkgeek This is a Magento error. It indicates a stack trace has been thrown.

Comment: @davidalger i edited the question.

Comment: @Marius i edited the question

Comment: You have a MySQL DB Admin issue and this question is close to being closed as far off topic. Once the proper credentials are in your Magento app/etc/local.xml file, you need to start looking elsewhere than Magento. From your MAMP installation may not have been done properly to you didn't properly set up your Magento database and grant proper privileges so that it's accessible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: [**ugly long number here**]

This is a way too often asked question, so this is one of those WIKI type items.

Your system has run into a problem so egregious that PHP throws a stack trace. It breaks PCI-DSS rules to have the stack trace message automatically show up as a web page as it can expose login credentials and other sensitive data (funny thing, ha ha, several somebodies posted full stack traces containing such sensitive contents over on the Magento Commerce forums over the years). So instead, it gets written to a file named with that **ugly long number here** you see in the above message.

These stack traces get written to `var/report/` **unless you've installed Magento** in such a manner that it cannot write to the folder due to bad file permissions.

Use your ftp client to display the contents of `var/report/` and choose the newest file (**ugly long number here**) to view the stack trace contents. The first line usually is the most important.

Post the contents of the latest stack trace (**obliterate login/db credentials**) with your question about how to fix it and you'll get better results.

---

Now for the concrete problem based on the original question and comments:

And here's what a stack trace from those numbered files stored in `var/report/` looks like (site specific path changed to /home/usracct/magento/):

```
a:4:{i:0;s:86:"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)";i:1;s:2652:"
#0 /home/usracct/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() 
#1 /home/usracct/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(313): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() 
#2 /home/usracct/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() 
#3 /home/usracct/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array) 
#4 /home/usracct/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8') 
#6 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)) 
#7 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')     #8 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write') 
#9 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter() 
#10 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter() 
#11 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(455): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions() 
#12 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(497): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions() 
#13 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config') 
#14 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config') 
#15 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit() 
#16 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache() 
#17 /home/usracct/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules() 
#18 /home/usracct/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#19 /home/usracct/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store') 
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:11:"/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/magento/index.php";}
```

And the first line pretty much states the problem. In this case, it's actually a MySQL issue involving database access.

```
"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

You probably need to check out your database access credentials in app/etc/local.xml and make sure that your db name, db user name and db password are all correctly entered (replace below with actual credentials). The section looks like this:

```
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[dbusername]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[dbpassword]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[dbname]]></dbname>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
```

This is also assuming that the database exists and that 'root'@'localhost' has been granted enough privileges to access the database.

After correcting the above issues, manually clear cache by deleting the `mage--?` subfolders in `var/cache/`.

Comment: i get this error http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d61sg789e

Comment: **These stack traces get written to** `var/report/` What you're showing **IS NOT A STACKTRACE**, so, what's in the file htdocs/ultraglow/var/report/341074319842

Comment: this is what it says http://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?60875e5b37b663a5#yYOABmgmN1biVjjWi8GDTWfj79lNycF0A1k3olDjwwk=

Comment: And did you even take the time to read what the error says??? It's pretty clear: you are using an incorrect username/password for MySql.

Comment: @davidalger yes i took a time to read, it says about password!!!i know how to read, but its not the case.duh!

Comment: @FiascoLabs thanks for the detailed answer, but my credentials are all set and right. the var/cahce content is deleted but i get the error. those things i did first before asking the question.

Comment: Can you log into the database from the command line using your credentials in your local.xml file? And do a show tables on that database? This appears to be quickly going off topic as a Magento issue and is becoming a MySQL issue.

Comment: There is one last server issue that may be affecting Magento. You have file permissions boogered up on your var/ folder. As this is MAMP and *nix rules apply, `chmod -R 777` on `var/` so Magento quits storing its cache in the system `/tmp/` folder rendering your clear cache null and void. One last Magento issue as well, there must be no other extraneous `localsave.xml` type files in `app/etc/` as Magento reads **all** `.xml` files in that folder and includes them in the configuration. Always rename `.xml` to something like `.xml.sv1`.