# What problem does this Magento Stack Trace report show?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, error-log

I have been getting error messages like this one:

```
> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
> disabled by default for security reasons.
> 
> Error log record number: 951974137800
```

I think these errors are happening about 100 times a day, by counting the average number of files in var/report/ each day.  I'd like to know how to fix the problem.

I've searched the Stack Exchange and found this advice ([There has been an error processing your request. Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number:](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8905/there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request)) stating that to troubleshoot this error, it is helpful to post the contents of the latest stack trace.  So, here are those contents:

```
> a:5:{i:0;s:2631:"SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
> `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
> IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM
> `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d`  LEFT JOIN
> `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id =
> t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id =
> 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64, 271, 273))
> AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('71', '98', '97', '87', '86', '118', '119',
> '122', '130')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT
> `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS
> `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS
> NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM
> `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_d`  LEFT JOIN
> `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id =
> t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id =
> 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64, 271, 273))
> AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('96', '102', '121', '100', '126', '123',
> '127', '125', '124', '128')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT
> `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS
> `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS
> NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM
> `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_d`  LEFT JOIN
> `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id =
> t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id =
> 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64, 271, 273))
> AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('75', '80', '76', '79', '120')) AND
> (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`,
> `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value`
> AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS
> `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_d`  LEFT JOIN
> `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id =
> t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id =
> 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64, 271, 273))
> AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('77', '78')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION
> ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS
> `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS
> NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM
> `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_d`  LEFT JOIN
> `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id =
> t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id =
> 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64, 271, 273))
> AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('101')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0)
> 
> ";i:1;s:3653:"#0
>     /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
> Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
> #1 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291):
> Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
> #2 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):
> Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
> #3 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `t_d`.`e...', Array)
> #4 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `t_d`.`e...', Array)
> #5 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `t_d`.`e...', Array)
> #6 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1111):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `t_d`.`e...')
> #7 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(480):
> Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadAttributes(false,
> false)
> #8 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(874):
> Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->_loadAttributes(false,
> false)
> #9 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741):
> Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
> #10 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(1493):
> Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
> #11 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Collection.php(182):
> Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->addOptionsToResult()
> #12 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Collection.php(139):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection->_assignProducts()
> #13 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(581):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection->_afterLoad()
> #14 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741):
> Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
> #15 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(758):
> Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
> #16 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(789):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->getAllItems()
> #17 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(196):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->hasItems()
> #18 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
> Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->indexAction()
> #19 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
> #20 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #21 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #22 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #23 /data/21/2/111/39/2111365/user/2316661/htdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #24 {main}";s:3:"url";s:18:"/checkout/onepage/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

What might be causing this stack trace?

Comment: If you navigate to your /errors folder, do you have a local.xml? If so, you can have the actual exception emailed to you and/or printed on screen using the configuration options in your local.xml or local.xml.sample, which you then rename to local.xml.

Comment: That database query works fine on my local system, was that the entire contents of the file at `var/report/951974137800`? There's no error message at the start of the file?

Comment: @jharrison.au - Yes. I just double-checked, and that was the entire contents of the file. I'm not sure why there is no error message at the start.

Comment: @ddavidn Thank you for this advice. I edited the local.xml.sample to email exception reports to me, and renamed to local.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Please post the entire contents of the file from `/var/report` as it probably has the actual error message at the top. But to help you start looking into the problem, reformatted for easy reading, this is the query that is failing:

```
SELECT 
    `t_d`.`entity_id`,
    `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
    `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
    `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
    IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
        t_d.value,
        t_s.value) AS `value`
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d`
        LEFT JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id
        AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id
        AND t_s.store_id = 1
WHERE
    (t_d.entity_type_id = 4)
        AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64 , 271, 273))
        AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('71' , '98',
        '97',
        '87',
        '86',
        '118',
        '119',
        '122',
        '130'))
        AND (t_d.store_id = 0) 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    `t_d`.`entity_id`,
    `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
    `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
    `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
    IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
        t_d.value,
        t_s.value) AS `value`
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_d`
        LEFT JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id
        AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id
        AND t_s.store_id = 1
WHERE
    (t_d.entity_type_id = 4)
        AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64 , 271, 273))
        AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('96' , '102',
        '121',
        '100',
        '126',
        '123',
        '127',
        '125',
        '124',
        '128'))
        AND (t_d.store_id = 0) 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    `t_d`.`entity_id`,
    `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
    `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
    `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
    IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
        t_d.value,
        t_s.value) AS `value`
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_d`
        LEFT JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id
        AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id
        AND t_s.store_id = 1
WHERE
    (t_d.entity_type_id = 4)
        AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64 , 271, 273))
        AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('75' , '80', '76', '79', '120'))
        AND (t_d.store_id = 0) 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    `t_d`.`entity_id`,
    `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
    `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
    `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
    IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
        t_d.value,
        t_s.value) AS `value`
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_d`
        LEFT JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id
        AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id
        AND t_s.store_id = 1
WHERE
    (t_d.entity_type_id = 4)
        AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64 , 271, 273))
        AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('77' , '78'))
        AND (t_d.store_id = 0) 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    `t_d`.`entity_id`,
    `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
    `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`,
    `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`,
    IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL,
        t_d.value,
        t_s.value) AS `value`
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_d`
        LEFT JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id
        AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id
        AND t_s.store_id = 1
WHERE
    (t_d.entity_type_id = 4)
        AND (t_d.entity_id IN (64 , 271, 273))
        AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('101'))
        AND (t_d.store_id = 0)
```

This is being called when something calls `hasItems()` on a `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` object. Why it's failing, I don't know. My suggestion is to run it against the database on the server that is causing the errors, (it's just a bunch of selects, and won't damage anything.) Or, as stated above, look at the very top of the report file for the error associated with this query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The report file that I posted is the complete report file that I can see in my text editor.  I do not see any error message at the start of the file, which is very strange.

Comment: Were you able to run the query directly against the database successfully?

Comment: You know, and I feel embarrassed saying it, but I don't know how to run a query. I'm looking for a tutorial now, but if you have a link you could share, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: In your MySQL database interface (usually phpMyAdmin), within the relevant database, look for the 'SQL' tab at the top, you can paste the query directly into there and run it.