# Magento manage category show error

Tags: admin, fatal-error

When I click on Manage Categories from admin it show me this error

> Magento Commerce There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 429737294153

Comment: Look in /var/report for the file with the name 429737294153    That file will give use more information about the error

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8905/there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request-exception-printing-is-disabled/8910#8910